# Regex to validate URL/URI without special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I need a regex to validate the given value is a URL or URI without ascii or special characters.

So valid scenarios :

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
2. /questions/ask

Invalid scenarios:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/@#$ds
2. questions/ask#*
3. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/@#$ds   ### (without spaces)`

How could this be achieved using a regex?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this one is a good place to start

```
^[https:\/\/|http:\/\/]?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9\.\/]+$
```

It's not exactly evident which are your limitations

1. Optional protocol
2. Optional the www. Clause
3. Limitation of accepted characters
4. Validation from start to finish `^` - `$`